# Send a string command to a socket

Tags: java, sockets

I am not very familiar with telnet so I would appreciate the help from any willing. 
I have smart plugs which can be switch on or off through a telnet interface.
I always use telnet via command prompt to connect to the server Digi X4 connect port (via >telnet  ). If I want to switch the socket on/off, I have to now type: "12 set pow=on/off" and press enter.
I would like to implement this through java using the telnet client. I am now able to connect to the port (thanks to the answers posted on this platform), but to send the command to switch devices on/off is proving difficult for me. I still have to type "12 set pow=on/off" and press enter. I would like Java to send this command.
Below is my java code. I would appreciate your assistance. Bab

```
public class TelnetConnection {

    static TelnetClient tc = null;

    public static void main(String[] a) throws Exception
    {
        String[] args = {"122.1222.181.45","8085"};
        System.out.println("arg value: "+args);

        if(args.length < 1)
        {
            System.err.println("Usage: Error <remote-ip> [<remote-port>]");
            System.exit(1);
        }

        String remoteip = args[0];

        int remoteport;

        if (args.length > 1)
        {
            remoteport = (new Integer(args[1])).intValue();
        }
        else
        {
            remoteport = 7000;
        }

           tc = new TelnetClient();

        while (true)
        {
            boolean end_loop = false;
            try
            {
                tc.connect(remoteip, remoteport);


                Thread reader = new Thread (new TelnetClientExample());
                tc.registerNotifHandler(new TelnetClientExample());
                System.out.println("TelnetClientExample");

                reader.start();
                OutputStream outstr = tc.getOutputStream();
                PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outstr);
                String buff = "11 set pow=on";
              //int ret_read = 0;
                do
                {
                    try
                    {
                        out.print(buff);
                        outstr.flush();
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.err.println("Error");
                        end_loop = true;
                    }
                }
                while((true) && (end_loop == false));

                try
                {
                    tc.disconnect();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                          System.err.println("Error");
                }
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                    System.err.println("Exception while connecting:" + e.getMessage());
                    System.exit(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `tring buff = "11 set pow=on\n"`; the server may need the newline to detect end-of-command.

By the way, the loop that infinitely sends that to the server looks worrisome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to send a line terminator corresponding to 'and press Enter'.

The line terminator in Telnet is defined as `\r\n`.